# SQL Server query- how to generate email of the contents before deleting an entity

Tags: sql-server, email

I am trying to write a query in SQL Server that will automatically generate an email to the email provided in the table as I delete that row. Is this possible?

What I'm trying to achieve is: in a row number, there is a column that states notes where approvers can add their notes. Sometimes I have to restart this specific row of number. So I wrote a query to put the overall status to draft (regardless of what status it is in now). In doing so, every other column becomes null. what I'm trying to achieve is that as I set this row number to draft, an automatic email is generated that will show the comments note section to the email provided within that row.

Is this possible?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes. For example, use a trigger with sp_send_dbmail

Comment: What does "set the row number to draft" mean?   Give an example.  It doesn't sound like you are really deleting the row.  This question is self-contradictory and confusing.

Comment: there are multiple rows eg Number 234, Number 235, Number 236 and so on. Before deleting Number 234(for eg), I want to generate automatic email with the column notes for this row. hope this is clearer.